# How to install react native CameraRoll?

Tags: react-native

I want to use CameraRoll in my react native application.
I've tryed to install it doing :

```
npm install RCTCameraRoll --save
```

but i get :

```
npm ERR! 404
```

what is the proper way to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Having just spent two hours on this, it's apparently still confusing nine months after your question.

The official documentation (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/cameraroll.html) points to the linking page which suggests that there's a package to install (which it points out must be referred to in `package.json` for automatic linking).

`RCTCameraRoll` is **already** included in your react-native npm installation (`node_modules/react-native/Libraries/CameraRoll`).  So no need to `npm` it.

However it's not linked in your Xcode project, so you *have to* follow the instructions in https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios.html for manual linking.

And what about Android?  That's not mentioned in the manual linking instructions.  No linking seems to be required.  `import {CameraRoll} from react-native` is all that's necessary.

Comment: Wow so much of inconsistency , this is one of the reasons not to consider RN for serious and big projects .

Comment: and in latest modules I can see no Xcode project anyways, so still no idea how to link it.

Comment: @vishaldharankar: https://railsware.com/blog/2017/10/09/best-examples-of-react-native-apps/ this is a list of all the successful projects by using RN. Are you sure about not to consider RN for **serious and big projects**?

Comment: @Isaac lets talk about regular tom , not insta , tesla etc. its hard to find info on certain topics like the above one, was it native I would have done dozens of time, by the time.

Comment: I couldn't find CameraRoll in the Libraries folder, so I found it in the react-native-community github. Please refer to instructions in https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-cameraroll